# I need to capture an owcarowsel plugin event,

Tags: javascript

I need to capture an owcarowsel plugin event, I have 7 sliders. Each time the slider automatically runs, a notification will appear with the serial number of the slider

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Comment: You need post actual code that you used. so anyone can just point you in right direction rather than adding code giving you entire description.